# How to fix ERROR: Site domain.com does not exist, while adding subdomain to apache2?

Tags: apache2, subdomain

I'm trying to add subdomains to my home server.

svn.domain.com
trac.domain.com

Due to dynamic IP I use dyndns service, on top of that I have domain.com hosted somewhere else. I created CNAME for subdomains on remote host to point to my user.dyndns.org domain.

So now when I visit either of subdomains: trac or svn, I see "It works!" message.

This done, I created two virtual host files under /etc/apache2/sites-enabled

file1: svn.domain.com and file2: trac.domain.com

contents:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

  ServerName trac.domain.com

   DocumentRoot = /var/www/trac/repos

   <Directory /var/www/trac/repos>
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
   </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

And

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

  ServerName svn.domain.com

   DocumentRoot = /var/svn/repos

   <Directory /var/svn/repos>
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
   </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

But I get error: ERROR: Site trac.domain.com does not exist!

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You want serverfault or something similar - stackoverflow is read by software developers rather than sysadmin.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try moving the files to /sites-available. Then run `a2ensite svn.domain.com` and `a2ensite trac.domain.com` and reload Apache.

Comment: Syntax error on line 5 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/trac.domain.com:
DocumentRoot takes one argument, Root directory of the document tree
Action 'configtest' failed.

Comment: Try removing `=` from DocumentRoot directive: `DocumentRoot  /var/www/trac/repos`

Comment: Something that tripped me up was that I was doing a2ensite on the subdomain name, which was wrong. You need to run a2ensite on the *file*.

Comment: As @Joseph mentioned, you have to run a2ensite on the conf file, so the naming of that file is all that matters. Otherwise, just run a2ensite withouth specifying the name, you can choose from the list then.

Answer (score 111):

I had this problem when upgrading from Apache 2.2 to Apache 2.4. The (ridiculous) solution was to ensure all files end with `.conf`, or `a2ensite` would `ERROR: Site example does not exist!`.

Also, when linked manually in `sites-enabled`, they would not even load without the `.conf` extension.

Comment: Umm, why in the world do we need .conf at the end of these vhost files now?  Really silly if you ask me.  Still thanks a lot for the answer!  I was pulling my hair out.

Comment: That is just because some programmer thought there is too much hair on this world! Because I did the same. :D

Comment: But seriously, I cannot understand either how the responsible programmer can think it is perfectly fine to leave breaking changes undocumented.

Comment: Exactly the same with me. Thanks.

Comment: Please make sure if your domain such as `somename.dev`, then your `.conf` file also should be `somename.dev.conf`

Comment: I'm not angry at the change, I'm angry at the `a2ensite` documentation which is not updated accordingly. Thx for this answer.

Comment: Thank you for this, I was also wondering what was wrong and this was it!

Comment: Another reason to finally drop Apache and use one of the many excellent alternatives.

Answer (score 19):

I also came across the same problem when I upgraded from Apache 2.2 to 2.4; all my virtual hosts suddenly broke and while trying to search for why this was the case, I stumbled across this question.

It turns out the reason is because of a difference between my old `apache2.conf` and the new `apache2.conf`. My old Apache 2.2 conf file had the line

```
Include sites-enabled/
```

whereas my new Apache 2.4 conf file had the line

```
IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf
```

Lo and behold, when I changed the line to

```
IncludeOptional sites-enabled/
```

everything went back to normal.

Comment: Thanks a lot for these explanations !

Comment: This is really useful info. Now we just need to figure out how to get a2ensite working again.

Comment: I swore I tried renaming to .conf and it didn't work...I tried again and it did work. a2ensite is a perl script and has been updated to only allow *.conf files. ...so yeah, the "Right" way to set up vhosts from now on is by naming all sites *.conf. Thanks Obama!

Comment: thanks to this I added a new line "IncludeOptional sites-enabled/" and there you go it works. I am using LMDE but I think this might have been a problem in the Upstream. So every debian distro might have got this update.

Answer (score 5):

if you type a2ensite. it will prompt. Which sites do you want to enable (ie., after you put a .conf file in the sites-available and link it from sites-enabled.

a2ensite expect the full name of the conf file with the .conf extension

Comment: I had the .conf extension as I had encountered this problem before. BUT when you get the default name using tab, for example type "a2ensite t..." press tab and get the name autofilled for you IT LEAVES OFF THE .CONF extension. You have to type the .conf.

Answer (score 3):

a2ensite ONLY accepts .conf files, so copy all sites in sites-available so the have a .conf extension (renaming didn't work itconfused the linkssomehow), erase the original files from sites-available AND sites-enabled. use a2ensite on the new files (you don't need to add .conf) and it all works, with our without the *.conf in /etc/apache2/apach2.conf

There must be some "memory" of the original file even when it is renamed -the symbolic link renames also, butthe erases & enabling "new" .con files works and you can then use a2dissite and a2ensite as before

Answer (score 1):

My solution for local server name is replacing:

```
sudo a2ensite serverName
```

with

```
sudo a2ensite serverName.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

1) remove all default site inside sites-enable

```
a2dissite <site-configuration-file-name>
```

2) take a closed look at your config file: start with a minimum properties like:

```
<VirtualHost [Domain]:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
ServerName [Domain]
DocumentRoot [webAppPath]

<Directory [webAppPath]>
    AllowOverride All
     Order allow,deny
     Allow from all
     Require all granted
</Directory>


ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/my_domain_name_error.log

CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/my_domain_name_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```